# mySQL ordering and distinct

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a review system on my website where users (profiles) can leave reviews for others. This part works fine.

But on my home page i want to get 10 of the latest reviews BUT i don't want to duplicate any users/profiles (i.e if a user has 2 reviews i only want the most recent)

Adding DISTINCT does not do this as all reviews/rows are unique.
(i do add DISTINCT though as some users submit duplicate reviews...)

I have tried GROUP BY ProfileID but this does not necessarily return the most recent review and i can not work out how to do this.
(GROUP BY kind of has the desired effect, but i think may be mixing up the data and is not getting the results in date order)

The below (simplified) SQL is what i currently have, but this brings back more than 1 review per user (if they have more than 1)

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(r.ReviewText, 100) as Review, r.ReviewRating, r.ReviewDate,
p.ProfileName, p.Location, p.ProfileID,
((date_format(now(),'%Y') - date_format(p.DateOfBirth,'%Y')) - (date_format(now(),'00-%m-%d') < date_format(p.DateOfBirth,'00-%m-%d'))) AS Age
FROM tReview r
INNER JOIN tProfiles p ON p.ProfileID = r.tProfiles_ProfileID                                                       
WHERE r.ReviewWithdrawn = 0
  AND r.ReviewEnabled = 1
  AND p.Enabled = 1
ORDER BY r.ReviewDate DESC                    
LIMIT 10
```

Any ideas (without filtering in php) as to how i can retrieve 10 results, in date order but only including each user once (so if the user has 2 reviews only the most recent will be returned)?

Comment: did you already see this SO post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira thanks, sounds just like what i need, although they explained it better then me. Thanks Again!

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira thanks but i cant get any method to work for me :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first select max date per user from `reviews` and then join back to itself and `profiles` to grab all other columns.

```sql
SELECT LEFT(r.ReviewText, 100) as Review, 
       r.ReviewRating, r.ReviewDate, p.ProfileName, p.Location, p.ProfileID,
       ((date_format(now(),'%Y') - date_format(p.DateOfBirth,'%Y')) - 
        (date_format(now(),'00-%m-%d') < date_format(p.DateOfBirth,'00-%m-%d'))) AS Age
  FROM
(
  SELECT p.ProfileID, MAX(r.ReviewDate) ReviewDate
    FROM tReview r JOIN tProfiles p 
      ON r.tProfiles_ProfileID = p.ProfileID
   WHERE r.ReviewWithdrawn = 0
     AND r.ReviewEnabled = 1
     AND p.Enabled = 1
   GROUP BY p.ProfileID
   ORDER BY ReviewDate DESC
   LIMIT 10
) q JOIN tReview r 
      ON q.ProfileID = r.tProfiles_ProfileID
     AND q.ReviewDate = r.ReviewDate 
    JOIN tProfiles p 
      ON r.tProfiles_ProfileID = p.ProfileID
```